# Running .sh file from python script

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to run a `.sh` file from a python script. However, the `.sh` file contains in it a function that requires inputs. 
So if I were to run the `.sh` file from the terminal it would look like:

`./test.sh 1 2`

I can see that in python, `subprocess.call(['./test.sh'])` won't work because there is no room for arguments. Is there any other branch of subprocess I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments are additional elements in the list.

```
subprocess.run(['./test.sh', '1', '2'])
```

You should also use `subprocess.run()` rather than `subprocess.call()`, which is an obsolete method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Have a look here in the docs:
Python2:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Python3.8:
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html

example:

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Comment: This is not hopelessly wrong, but linking to Python 2 documentation in 2020 is probably a habit you want to consider dropping.

Answer (score -3):

You can do too with the function:

```
try:
    ressys = subprocess.check_call('script.sh',  shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    res = str(e.output) + " -- Code: " + str(e.returncode)
    print res
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which is how to provide the arguments to the script.

Comment: "shell=True" can be dangerous. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: You can provide arguments to the script this way:  subprocess.check_call("script.sh param1 param2", shell=True)

Comment: That should be in the answer, not a comment. And there's still no reason to use the shell just to parse a string into a list which you could have provided in the first place.